# Loading part of big image from disk with Xamarin

Tags: ios, image, xamarin

Is there any way with Xamarin to load only part of an image directly from disk in iOS?

What I need to do is create tiles from potentially huge images (10k x 10k) to be able to display them as tiles. Is there any way of doing this with Xamarin without loading the whole image into memory which crashes the program?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is OS dependent, Xamarin doesn't have a cross platform image library as far as I understand. You should refer to iOS documentation.

Comment: Yes, the question was specifically for iOS. I cannot find any way of doing this in Xamarin (or ObjC for that matter).